# Add vertical lines on batch ggplots based on other dataframe attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2, batch-processing, subset

this could sound as a weird question... I hope I can explain what I'm trying to do.

I have written this small piece of code in order to perform a batch-plotting with ggplot:

```
by(dataset_melted, dataset_melted$variable, function(i){
    ggplot(i) +
    stat_ecdf(aes(x=value, color=Area))
})
```

Now what I'd need is to use geom_vline in order to add a vertical line to each plot.

The glitch is that the vertical value is stored in another data frame, but the name is the same of the `variable` of the data frame `dataframe_melted`.

In other word, the code of above plots chemical distributions and I need to add a vertical line that is a threshold value.

This small piece of code works for one element:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=dataset$As, color=Area))+
    stat_ecdf() +
    geom_vline(data=subset(threshold, Element %in% c("As"), xintercept=threshold$LCB))
```

Is there a way to include this `geom_vline` in the `by` function?

**EDIT** here a piece of the two data frames.

This is the first one:

```
structure(list(Area = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L), .Label = c("Lido_Spina", "Porto_Corsini", "Punta_Marina", 
"Sito1", "Sito2", "candiano"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L), .Label = c("Sabbia", 
"Pelite", "PCB_101", "PCB_105", "PCB_114", "PCB_118", "PCB_123", 
"PCB_126", "PCB_138", "PCB_153_168", "PCB_156", "PCB_157", "PCB_167_128", 
"PCB_169", "PCB_180_193", "PCB_189", "PCB_31_28", "PCB_52", "PCB_77", 
"PCB_81", "PCB_totali", "Acenaftene", "Acenaftilene", "Antracene", 
"Benzo.a.antracene", "Benzo.a.pirene", "Benzo.b._.j.fluorantene", 
"Benzo.ghi.perilene", "Benzo.k.fluorantene", "Crisene", "Dibenzo.ac._.ah.antracene", 
"Fenantrene", "Fluorantene", "Fluorene", "Indeno.1.2.3.c.d.pirene", 
"Naftalene", "Pirene", "Sommatoria_IPA", "Al", "As", "Cd_totale", 
"Cr_totale", "Hg", "Ni_totale", "Pb_totale", "Cu_totale", "V", 
"Zn_totale", "N_totale", "P_totale", "C_org_totale", "Composti_organostannici", 
"Idrocarburi_C12", "Idrocarburi_C_12", "Aldrin", "Alfa_esaclorocicloesano", 
"Beta_esaclorocicloesano", "Esaclorobenzene", "Sommatoria_DDD", 
"Sommatoria_DDE", "Sommatoria_DDT", "Dieldrin", "Lindano", "Endrin", 
"Eptacloro", "Eptacloro_epossido", "Clordano_cis", "Clordano_trans", 
"Metossicloro", "Nonacloro_cis", "Nonacloro_trans", "Mirex", 
"Profo", "X_2mm", "X_2000.63mm", "X_63.4mm", "X_4mm", "res105"
), class = "factor"), value = c(8.45, 7.82, 6, 8.7, 10.1, 8.64, 
6, 8.38, 9.16, 7.7, 7, 7.66, 9.19, 9.48, 8.35, 8.37, 7.5, 5.5, 
6.45, 6.22, 9.3, 8.62, 8, 6, 7, 7.75, 6.17, 5.71, 9, 8.75, 13.5, 
7.75, 7.6, 8.33, 8, 8.75, 7.4, 8.25, 8.17, 7.75, 7.6, 7.5, 7.2, 
8, 7.83, 7.75, 7, 7.5, 8.17, 8.75, 6.67, 7, 5.83, 6.75, 5.6, 
6.4, 6.2, 6.2, 6.2, 6.25, 7, 6, 6, 6.4, 6, 5.8, 5.6, 6, 6, 5.8, 
7.25, 8.8, 8.5, 8, 8.25, 8.25, 8.5, 8.25, 8.25, 8.5, 8, 8.25, 
8.25, 8.25, 8, 7.25, 6.67, 7.33, 8, 8, 8, 7.67, 7.67, 6.33, 6.33, 
7, 7, 6, 7.67, 8, 8, 9.5, 8, 8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 8, 7.8, 
8.2, 8.4, 8.6, 6.6, 8.5, 8, 6.5, 6.75, 6.2, 6, 7, 6.5, 6, 7, 
6, 5, 7, 6, 7, 7.67, 10, 8, 9, 7.5, 7.33, 6.8, 7, 7, 8, 8, 7.25, 
7, 8, 7, 7, 9, 9, 7.8, 7, 6.17, 7, 7.75, 7, 6.17, 7, 7.6, 6.5, 
7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 6.6, 6.6, 0.14, 0.14, 0.025, 0.15, 0.15, 0.14, 
0.025, 0.16, 0.18, 0.16, 0.025, 0.15, 0.14, 0.12, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.17, 0.11, 0.05, 0.05, 0.12, 0.15, 0.12, 0.025, 0.17, 0.16, 
0.1, 0.05, 0.15, 0.13, 0.15, 0.1, 0.16, 0.13, 0.24, 0.15, 0.22, 
0.13, 0.15, 0.1, 0.16, 0.18, 0.2, 0.15, 0.13, 0.15, 0.17, 0.13, 
0.13, 0.13, 0.18, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1, 0.13, 
0.11, 0.1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.09, 0.11, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11, 0.09, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.14, 0.12, 0.12, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.12, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.13, 0.11, 0.09, 0.1, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.07, 0.09, 0.1, 0.1, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 
0.1, 0.08, 0.11, 0.1, 0.12, 0.11, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.22, 0.24, 
0.28, 0.1, 0.15, 0.13, 0.1, 0.1, 0.12, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.13, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.13, 0.1, 0.13, 0.1, 0.12, 0.12, 0.16, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.15, 0.1, 0.14, 0.12, 84.3, 83.9, 52, 98.7, 100.4, 91.5, 63, 
94.2, 100.8, 91.5, 47, 86.8, 99.7, 90, 88.7, 88.4, 99.8, 76.4, 
57.8, 52.5, 83.4, 93.5, 85.9, 57, 93.9, 97.9, 53.9, 56.1, 108.5, 
111.75, 104.5, 81.25, 93.2, 109.75, 105, 104, 87.8, 99.75, 92.67, 
104.5, 88.2, 77, 70.6, 92.25, 84.83, 78.5, 70.17, 92.5, 94.67, 
93.75, 70.5, 86.6, 77.67, 64.75, 66, 75.6, 82.4, 80.2, 78.8, 
81, 79, 75.6, 79.2, 79.6, 71.6, 73.2, 75.2, 43.6, 54, 35.6, 63.25, 
95.4, 85.75, 84.5, 78.25, 82.75, 87.25, 86.05, 85, 96, 102.25, 
100.5, 100, 94.75, 90.67, 85.75, 76.67, 86.33, 93.67, 89.33, 
90.33, 83.67, 86.33, 74, 73.67, 86.67, 87.5, 72, 89.67, 93, 95, 
93, 91, 91, 86, 89, 99, 98, 84, 84, 81, 90, 101.2, 102.6, 96.6, 
108, 75.6, 105, 98, 69.5, 79.75, 68.6, 79, 91, 87, 70, 95.25, 
67, 55, 90, 65, 79, 102.67, 102, 76, 101, 87.5, 96.67, 77.4, 
79, 90.33, 96, 88, 96.25, 84, 90, 86.5, 85, 100.25, 103, 97.8, 
82, 59.33, 98, 100.75, 81, 61.17, 64.6, 84.8, 71.5, 73, 95, 94, 
107, 107.5, 93, 70.2, 70.2)), .Names = c("Area", "variable", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 6553:7056)
```

and that of the threshold values:

```
structure(list(Elemento = structure(c(3L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 20L, 
22L, 23L, 30L, 8L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 15L, 
29L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 21L, 25L), .Label = c("Acenaftene", 
"Antracene", "As", "Benzo(a)antracene", "Benzo(a)pirene", "Cd_totale", 
"Clordano", "Composti_organostannici", "Crisene", "Cr_totale", 
"Cu_totale", "Dibenzo(ac)_(ah)antracene", "Dieldrin", "Endrin", 
"Eptacloro_epossido", "Esaclorocicloesano", "Fenantrene", "Fluorantene", 
"Fluorene", "Hg", "Naftalene", "Ni_totale", "Pb_totale", "PCB_totali", 
"Pirene", "Sommatoria_DDD", "Sommatoria_DDE", "Sommatoria_DDT", 
"Sommatoria_IPA", "Zn_totale"), class = "factor"), LCB = c(25, 
0.35, 100, 40, 0.4, 70, 40, 100, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    LCL = c(32, 0.8, 360, 52, 0.8, 75, 70, 170, 72, 189, 7.8, 
    3.7, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 62, 1, 2.7, 4000, 89, 245, 693, 763, 
    846, 135, 544, 1494, 144, 391, 1398)), .Names = c("Elemento", 
"LCB", "LCL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use facets instead of `by`? First merge your melted dataset with your threshold values, and then call:

```
ggplot(dataset_melted, aes(value, color=Area, xintercept=LCB)) + stat_ecdf() + geom_vline() + facet_wrap(~variable)
```

That might not be quite right - can you check your last piece of code? Without your data, I can't tell for sure, but it might not be plotting the vline.

Comment: the problem is that merging the dataframes, in this particular case, is not that easy..

Comment: Why do you say that? Are they very large?

Comment: I edited my question with a piece of the data frames. Actually the size is not the problem, the problem is "conceptual". The first data frames contains sample values, while the second is just a table with law threshold values..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it with `by` because I'm not sure how to tell `by` to iterate over the group levels in the second data set. But here's an approach using `lapply` instead. You didn't post any data, so I've used the built-in `mtcars` data set as an example that hopefully you can adapt to your needs:

```
library(dplyr)

# Mean weight for each value of cyl
meanWT = mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(wt))

# Plot for each value of cyl
lapply(sort(unique(mtcars$cyl)), function(i) {
    ggplot(mtcars[mtcars$cyl==i,]) +
      geom_point(aes(wt, mpg)) +
      geom_vline(data=meanWT[meanWT$cyl==i,], aes(xintercept=mean))
})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but I cannot run your code: `Error: could not find function "%>%"`...

Comment: You might need to install a recent version of dplyr (`install.packages("dplyr")`) or magrittr (`install.packages("magrittr")`).

Comment: Or, if you don't want to bother with `dplyr` you can do this: `meanWT = aggregate(wt ~ cyl, FUN=mean, data=mtcars)`.